# $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$, $f \in \mathscr{C}^0$ and $\exists~ m$ such that $f^{(m)}(x)=x$ for all $x \in[0,1] .$ Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, solution-verification, fixed-points

This is an AoPS thread [post.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h2221138_calculus_problem)

---

$\blacksquare~$ **Problem:** Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow[0,1]$ be a continuous function such that $f^{(n)}:=f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f ~(n \text { times) and assume that there exists a positive integer } m$ such that $f^{(m)}(x)=x$ for all $x \in[0,1] .$ Prove that $f(x)=x$ for all $x \in[0,1]$

---

$\blacksquare~$ **My Approach:**

A small claim at first. The problem is not true for $m$ even.

$\bullet~$ **Counter Example:** Just as described in the post, take the function $f(x) = 1 - x~$ for all $x \in [0, 1].$ Then we have that $$ f^2(x) = x \quad \text{for }x \in [0, 1] $$
Therefore we can conclude that for $m = 2k$ [for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}]$ the statement of the problem can't be true (of course if the statement is changed to $\color{red}{\text{some}}$ instead of $\color{blue}{\text{for all}}$, then it's trivially true as by IVT, there exists $c \in [0, 1]$ such that $f(c) = c$).

Then $m $ must be odd.

$\bullet~$ **Solution (when $m$ is odd):**

Let $m = (2k + 1)$ . then If $m$ is odd, let $m = (2k + 1)$. Now, we have a claim.

$\bullet \bullet~ \textbf{Claim:}$ The map $f$ $\in$ $\mathscr{C}^{0}[0, 1]$ is monotonic.(this is independent of the parity of $m$).

$\bullet \bullet~ \textit{Proof:}$ Consider $x, y$ $\in$ $[0, 1]$ such that
\begin{align*}
&f(x) = f(y)\\
\implies &f^{m}(x) = f^{m}(y)\quad [\text{taking } f \circ f \circ \cdots \circ f]\\
\implies & x = y \quad [\text{as } f^{m}(x) = x ~ \text{for any } x \in [0, 1] ]
\end{align*}Hence $f$ is one-one + $f$ $\in$ $~\mathscr{C}^{0}$ $\implies$ $f$ is monotonic in $[0, 1]$.

$\bullet~$ Then consider the function $g$ $\in$ $\mathscr{C}^{0}$ such that it's defined as$$ g(x) := f(x) - x \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, 1] $$By IVT, we have that for some $c$ $\in$ $[0, 1]$ $g(c) = 0 \implies f(c) = c$.

$\bullet~$ Now WLOG let's consider $f$ is decreasing. Therefore
$$ f(x) < x \quad \text{for any } x \in (c, 1] \quad \text{and }~ f(x) > x \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, c) $$Then we have that
\begin{align*}
\implies&f^2(x) > f(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in (c, 1] \quad \text{and }~ f^2(x) < f(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, c) \\
&~~~~~~~~~~ \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad  \vdots\\
\implies& f^{2k} (x) > f^{2k - 1}(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in (c, 1] \quad \text{and }~ f^{2k}(x) < f^{2k - 1}(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, c) \\
\implies & x < f^{2k}(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in (c, 1] \quad \text{and }~ x > f^{2k}(x) \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, c) \\
\implies & f(x) > x \quad \text{for any } x \in (c, 1] \quad \text{and }~ f(x) < x \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, c) 
\end{align*}Which is a clear **contradiction**. Hence, we have that
$$ f(x) = x \quad \text{for any } x \in (c, 1] \quad \text{and }~ f(x) = x \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, c)  $$And as $f(c) = c$, therefore we have that $f(x) = x \quad \text{for any } x$ $\in$ $[0, 1]$.

$\bullet~$ $\textbf{If } f \textbf{ was increasing:}$ Then we would have had
$$ f(x) > x \quad \text{for any } x \in (c, 1] \quad \text{and }~ f(x) < x \quad \text{for any } x \in [0, c) $$And again by the same procedure we can boil it down!

---

Can someone suggest another proof? And please verify this one for glitches.

Comment: Just curious:   Is there a reason for discussing the problem here, rather than on AoPS?  Keeping all discussion in the same place can reduce duplication of efforts.

Comment: Yeah, just cause I was curious someone would come up with another approach. (and as the asker of the question doesn't seem to have any such enthusiasm for new answers) @GEdgar :)